# Configure SSL on Windows HTTP server using HTTPAPI_VERSION_1 APIs

Tags: windows, ssl, https

I configured SSL on my Windows HTTP server (HTTP listener) developed using `HTTPAPI_VERSION_1` APIs using `HttpSetServiceConfiguration`.

I used a self signed certificate and followed the steps at this link to set it as trusted http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/29/walkthrough-using-httplistener-as-an-ssl-simple-server.aspx

Then I tried using the sample in msdn named `WinHttpPostSample` to connect to the http server using https.

But `WinHttpSendRequest` API always fails with error

> 12044 (ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED)

How can we prevent the HTTP server from sending this error or to make it not compulsory for the server to have a client certificate to proceed ?